# Cross-Account IAM Access Using AWS SDK via assumed-role giving error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sts

I am attempting to assume a role in another AWS account through an assumed role, authorising using the `WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider` via the AWS STS SDK. This is ran on a `k8s` instance, with credentials provided to access a specific role within an account.

e.g. **Account 1** has credentials on the `k8s` pod for the `account-1-role`, and wants to assume the `my-query-role` role that exists in **Account 2**.

My current policy looks like this:

**Account 1 `account-1-role` Permission Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::<account_2_id>:role/my-query-role"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Account 2 `my-query-role` Trust Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account_1_id>:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Java**

```java
AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.create();

StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder()
        .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
        .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
        .build();

AssumeRoleRequest assumeRoleRequest = AssumeRoleRequest.builder()
        .roleArn("arn:aws:iam::<account_2_id>:role/my-query-role")
        .roleSessionName(MANAGED_PROMETHEUS_ROLE_SESSION)
        .build();

AssumeRoleResponse assumeRoleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(assumeRoleRequest);
```

**Problem**

However, then when I attempt to assume through the role through the AWS `StsClient`, I get the following error:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.StsException: User: arn:aws:sts::<account_1_id>:assumed-role/<account_1_role>/aws-sdk-java-1680536628314 
is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<account_2_id>:role/my-query-role 
(Service: Sts, Status Code: 403, Request ID: 9aa79d21-344f-41b1-a251-8f81bb23af8c)
```

My question is, do I have to provide a separate policy for the `StsClient` to be able to use the permission? I thought from reading the documentation that the assumed-role would have the same policy as the parent role, so would be trusted by **Account 2**. However the ARN does seem to be in a different format

e.g. `arn:aws:sts::<account_1_id>:assumed-role` rather than `arn:aws:sts::<account_1_id>:role`

Answer (score 0):

Trust Policy for `my-query-role` IAM Role in Account 2 is wrong in your case.

You should update the **Principal** field to have the ARN of account 1's IAM Role `account-1-role`.

#### Trust Policy - IAM Role - Account 2

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "<THIS SHOULD BE THE ARN OF IAM ROLE IN ACCOUNT 1>"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - however I have updated the `IAM` policy to match the above and it's still not working. e.g. I'm getting the same error